# add new gstreamer capability

Tags: capability, gstreamer

I want to add a new capability to existing capability list in gstreamer. Can anybody help me to understand following questions.

1. What is a data class in gstreamer?
2. How can I add a new capability by reusing the existing data class?

Thanks in advance

Raju Babannavar

Answer (score 0):

You should most definitely read this: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/pwg/html/